# How do you mock a function call in chefspec for an object instance extended with another class

Tags: unit-testing, chef-infra, chefspec

I am new to unit testing and chefspec. I am trying to mock/intercept a function call in a recipe from a dependent library

- Library

  ```
  module Helper
    def do_something_useful
      return "http://example.com/file.txt"
    end
  end
  ```
- Recipe

  ```
  remote_file '/save/file/here' do
    extend Helper
    source do_something_useful
  end
  ```

I have tried the following:

- Chefspec

  ```
  allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Resource::RemoteFile).to receive(:do_something_useful).and_return('foobar')
  allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Resource).to receive(:do_something_useful).and_return('foobar')
  ```

  I have also tried mocking with a double:

  ```
  helper = double
  Helper.stub(:new).and_return(helper)
  allow(helper).to receive(:do_something_useful).and_return('foobar')
  ```

  This fails with `uninitialized constant Helper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooooo this is a fun case where the `extend` is overwriting the mock method. So we can just use the `extend` to drive things:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Resource::RemoteFile).to receive(:extend) do |this, m|
    Module.instance_method(:extend).bind(this).call(m)
    allow(this).to receive(:do_something_useful).and_return('foobar')
  end
end
```

This is like 800% magic and you probably shouldn't use it, but it does work in my little test environment.